My mistakes tikzpicture
Two problems: 1) Why do the text "Hello Hello Hello" next to the text "Bye bye bye" if they are in different places in the code? 2) Why did the picture F_x(t) go to the second page with such a large indentation?
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=25mm,top=20mm,right=25mm,bottom=30mm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    width=\linewidth,   scale only axis,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}


\begin{document} 
Hello Hello Hello
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, 
    ylabel = {$x$}, 
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=2,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:2, samples=1000, color=orange] {0.4+0.5*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$x=x_0+v_{0x}t+\frac{a_xt^2}{2}$}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, 
    ylabel = {$S_x$}, 
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=2,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:2, samples=1000, color=orange] {0.5*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$S_x=v_{0x}t+\frac{a_xt^2}{2}$}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$v_x$}, % подпись оси y
    xmin=-2,
    ymin=-2, ymax=10,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {1+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$v_x=v_{0x}+a_xt$}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, 
    ylabel = {$a_x$}, 
    xmin=-2,
    ymin=-2, ymax=10,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$a_x=\text{const}$}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
Bye Bye Bye 
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    width=0.4\linewidth,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$},
    ylabel = {$F_x$},
    xmin=-2,
    ymin=-2, ymax=10,
]
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:5, samples=1000, color=orange] {1-x};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}





Change option [h] to [!h] which overwrite default size for floats partition of page (70%). Newer use just [h], more correct is enable to LaTeX more option for float placement. For example \[ht].

Addition to first comment: your images occupy to much space on page, consequently the second is moved to the next page. For more details see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats.

figure tells latex move this thing to the best place you can. h means here would be great, if it fits. [h] means here would be great, if it fits, but don't put it anywhere else, if it doesn't fit, and do find a good place for it. so latex changes [h] to [ht]. don't use a floating environment if you don't want it to move ;).

You use floats (although you use h), which means that these parts are not positioned in the normal text flow per default.

Let me spell out comment to your question:

by default a document's page can be filled 100% by text (and equation)
if you like to change default settings, consider instruction on FAQ, where are listed the following commands with default values:

 \renewcommand{\topfraction}{.85}
 \renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.7}
 \renewcommand{\textfraction}{.15}
 \renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.66}
 \renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.66}
 \renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.66}
 \setcounter{topnumber}{9}
 \setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
 \setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
 \setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}

this values you can change according to your needs.

if you like to change global settings just for one float, than please add exclamation mark (!) to placement option.
At using placement option please always obey @cfr comment. If not, you will be soon faced with new problems ...
That text "Bye Bye Bye" be in own paragraph, you need to write such, i.e. before it insert empty lines (see MWE below)
So, a possible solution of your question is:

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=25mm,top=20mm,right=25mm,bottom=30mm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    width=\linewidth,   scale only axis,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}


\begin{document} 
Hello Hello Hello
    \begin{figure}[!h]  % <----
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, 
    ylabel = {$x$}, 
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=2,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:2, samples=1000, color=orange] {0.4+0.5*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$x=x_0+v_{0x}t+\frac{a_xt^2}{2}$}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, 
    ylabel = {$S_x$}, 
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=2,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:2, samples=1000, color=orange] {0.5*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$S_x=v_{0x}t+\frac{a_xt^2}{2}$}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, % подпись оси x
    ylabel = {$v_x$}, % подпись оси y
    xmin=-2,
    ymin=-2, ymax=10,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {1+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$v_x=v_{0x}+a_xt$}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$}, 
    ylabel = {$a_x$}, 
    xmin=-2,
    ymin=-2, ymax=10,
]
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:10, samples=1000, color=orange] {5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$a_x=\text{const}$}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    
Bye Bye Bye             % <---- observe empty line before this line
    \begin{figure}[!h]  % <----
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[standard,
    width=0.4\linewidth,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xlabel = {$t$},
    ylabel = {$F_x$},
    xmin=-2,
    ymin=-2, ymax=10,
]
\addplot[line width=0.3 mm, domain=0:5, samples=1000, color=orange] {1-x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


